# iOS WatchKit - How to detect when back button is pressed on Watch?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, back-button, watchkit, popviewcontroller

I need to do some cleanup on 2nd view controller when the back button (arrow) is pressed on the Apple Watch. Is there any sort of method for detecting/handling when a back button is pressed / view is popped?

Note - I can't use 'willDeactivate()' function as it gets me stuck in a loop for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no method to detect that the back button was touched. The correct/only place would be in `didDeactivate`, though it sounds like that won't work for you.

Comment: So far this seems to be the case. I was able to rework my loop to do all the cleanup in 'willDeactivate', just not as pretty as I'd like. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot find the willDeactivate() method. Has this been removed in the latest version? Thanks

Comment: Actually, they've always been willActivate and didDeactivate. Edited my response.